# Transfer values from PHP to Google Maps in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a php script on altervista,which get data from an http request(including GPS coordinates). Evry time it receives a request,it should also shows corresponding coordinates on GoogleMaps( implemented on altervista)

```html
<?php
//controllo se sono presenti i parametri
if(isset($_GET['ID_utente']) && isset($_GET['Longitudine']) && isset($_GET['Latitudine']))
{
//Recupero il valore dei parametri
$ID_utente = $_GET['ID_utente'];
$Longitudine = $_GET['Longitudine'];
$Latitudine = $_GET['Latitudine'];
}

//eseguo la connessione al database sul server locale
//inserendo nome utente e password
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'realegr', 'pass', 'my_realegr');
 
//gestione degli errori
// if (!$conn) {die('Impossibile connettersi: ' . mysql_error());}
 
//seleziono il databse
mysql_select_db("my_realegr") or die( "Impossibile selezionare il 
database.");
 
//creo una stringa sql di inserimento con i valori
//recuperati dall'url
$sql = "INSERT INTO `my_realegr`.`DatiSinistro`
(
`ID_sinistro` ,
`Tempo_Server` ,
`Tempo_Locale` ,
`ID_utente`,
`Longitudine`,
`Latitudine`
)
VALUES
(
NULL , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , NULL , '" . $ID_utente . "', '" . $Longitudine . 
"', '" . $Latitudine . "')
";

$q = "SELECT Longitudine, Latitudine FROM DatiSinistro ORDER by ID_sinistro 
DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($q, $conn);

 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['Longitudine'];
    echo $row['Latitudine'];
    


//eseguo la query
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

 
//gestione degli errori
if(! $retval ){die('Impossibile eseguire la query: ' . mysql_error());}
 
//chiudo la connessione al db
mysql_close($conn);
echo "Database aggiornato.";

?>
```

I have the following script in a file html:

```html
        <script>
          function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: 45.062583, lng: 7.662160};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
          }
        </script>
```

So I need to use the value of $Latitudine and $Longitudine(in php script) as parameters of var in the function initMap

How could I transfer this values??

EDIT:ERROR IN CONSOLE:
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number;

InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: How are these two pieces of code related to each other?  Is this all on the same page?  Are you making an AJAX request to the PHP code from the JavaScript code?  Something else?  There are a variety of ways to use a value, but it depends on how you've structured things.

Comment: Do you use any framework?

Answer (score 0):

In php echo the a json containing all the data:

```
<?php
...............
$q = "SELECT Longitudine, Latitudine FROM DatiSinistro ORDER by ID_sinistro 
DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($q, $conn);

    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo json_encode([
           'status' => true,
           'latitude' => $row['Latitudine'],
           'longitude' => $row['Latitudine']
         ]
    }
.............
?>
```

On the javascript you make an ajax call request to the php file where you retrieve the request.

```
<script>
     var $request = $.get('PHP_SCRIPT_URL');
     $request.done = function(data) {
          var pasedData = JSON.parse(data);
          if(data.status == true)
               initMap(data.latitude, data.longitude);
     }
function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
     var uluru = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question,but what exactly do I have to write in 'PHP_SCRIPT_URL' ?Because it doesn't load the map when I try to load it :/

Comment: But you said in the question that the script is in a html file, so you have one single file with the php and html/js code? If yes just remove `PHP_SCRIPT_URL` and let empty quotes. Should point to the current file.

Comment: Oh sorry... You wrote page but i red domain eheh... No,they aren't on the same page

Comment: Puth the path of the PHP file there in the ajax.

Comment: It doesn't work anyway... When I try to use php script,it shows me: {"status":true,"latitude":"45.062583","longitude":"7.662160"‌​} So I think that part is ok...

Comment: Well that is perfect, as you access the script in browser `http://localhost.com/myscript.php` put it like this: `$.get('http://localhost.com/myscript.php');`

Comment: Sorry but I noticed only now some errors in console when I load html page ( as I said I am pretty newbie in these arguments and I didn't know that html load a page even with a error..my bad...).
I copy them in main post